# glyphicon being able to use the @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The situation is this, when I type something on the input text the `glyphicon-remove` will show and then when i clicked it, it will supposedly reset the `search`.

This is my code

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" v-on:input="fetchProducts()" v-model="search" style="margin-top:15px;" placeholder="Search">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" v-if="search" @click="search=''"></i>
</div>
```

My problem is, when i clicked the `glyphicon-remove` it do nothing

Comment: can you share any live demo ?

Comment: http://vue-table-component.spatie.be/ look on the filter search that's what i want to happened thanks

Comment: I am saying your live demo which is not working ? add snippet with all code ?

Comment: here sir http://jsfiddle.net/r3md1w5o/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    search:""
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
   <input type="text" class="" v-model="search" style="margin-top:15px;" placeholder="Search">
   <span v-show="search" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" @click="search=''"></span>
</div>
Searching : {{search}}
</div>
```

Comment: lmao the only issue is the class form-control-feedback if i return it will not function again